# Genymotion and PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA

Tags: android, camera, genymotion

I have found many questions concerning usage of Camera in Genymotion android emulator. I have finally solved the problem with activating Camera in Genymotion (though this feature seems to be buggy, and is working from time to time).

Now I am trying to make check for Camera availability by using following code:

```
PackageManager pm = PhotosSectionFragment.this.getActivity().getPackageManager();
pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)
```

But it always returns `false` to me, though using of following block for getting image

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, storeLocation);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestId);
```

works fine.
I suppose, that it is the bug of Genymotion, cause the same check works fine in AVD and on real device. But may be there is another way of doing same check, which will also work in Genymotion?

Comment: I tried and using the last version of Genymotion and a newly created device i get "true" for 
pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA). Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)` should always returns `true` on Genymotion.

But sometimes, if the connection to the webcam fails when device is starting, the feature will be disabled and the camera widget will not work until next restart.

I think this is what happened here.

Comment: In my case camera never connects, when virtual device starts, and I need manually activate it by Camera widget after device was initialized. Can you tell, how to make Genymotion connect camera on device start?